# _set_se_translator not working for a thread

Tags: multithreading, exception

I want to direct my exceptions raised  in thread using `_set_se_translator` function

Here is the implementation

**Thread**

```
_set_se_translator(ExceptionHandler)

Int x = 10;
Int y = x / 0;
```

**Exception handler**

```
Void ExceptionHandler( unsigned code, EXCEPTION_POINTERS*) 
{
Throw Exception(code);
}
```

**`Exception` Class**

```
class Exception
{
Public:
  Exception(unsigned codePar) { code =codePar}
Unsigned code;
Const char * getcodestring(void);
Char message[250];
};
```

**getcodestring finction**

```
Const char " Exception::getcodestring()
{
swtich(code)
{
Case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
Sprintf(message, "by zero");
Breask;
}
Return message
}
```

But I never got the divide by zero message infa t I think it's not going through the translator function in my thread

This is what I am getting

```
Unhandled win32 structured exception
Code : C000094
```

Where is that I am missing?

PN: there is no try catch block in my thread. Assuming the exception is caught by the translator

Comment: Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You still need to catch the exception as `_set_se_translator` only translated it from C structured exception to C++ typed exception.

```
try
{
    _set_se_translator(ExceptionHandler)

    int x = 10;
    int y = x / 0;
}
catch(const Exception& ex)
{
  // handle here
}
```